# List files having more than 100 lines in a directory and in all it's sub directory

Tags: command-line, files

How can I list files having more than 100 lines in a directory and in all its sub directories? An example of such a terminal command will be very helpful.

Is there a tool to count the line numbers of given files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the following command:

```
find <folder-to-search> -name "*.txt" -type f -exec sh -c 'test `wc -l {} | cut -f1 -d" "` -gt "100"' \; -print
```

Also take a look at the `-name` parameter, currently you will find only files that end with `.txt`. You want to alter that or, just delete the parameter and the argument to find all files.

Answer (score 8):

You can count lines with `wc`, the word count utility:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l | sort -n
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit n the answer. It is working nicely. Would you plz describe the command a bit?

Comment: Sure. The `find` command prints out all the files in the current directory and its subdirectories. `xargs` receives that list of files and passes them to a series of `wc -l` commands, which print the line count of each those files. `sort -n` sorts the list of files numerically by their line counts. Strictly speaking, it would be more efficient if we could tell `wc` to stop counting after reaching 100 lines, but I'm not aware of a way to do that.

Comment: Thanks paul for your kind help. It does nicely, what it exactly suppose to do, but i just want the files that have more than 100 lines and thats where @ortang 's command is more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line with awk as well, wanted to add it as a comment to support Paul
s answer but due to >> echo "1 reputation" | awk '$1<50' reputation I couldn't :D

```
find . -type f | xargs wc -l | awk -F "." '$1>100'
```

Optional --> -name that ortang mentioned with find... and -F is the delimiter, even default space can work like "awk "$1>100"